# Spring annotation ignored in Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0

Tags: spring, annotations, weblogic12c

after deploying my application Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 , i got the below error :

> Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry
>   com/hps/common/crypto/api/IObjectEncoder.class not found in
>   /wls/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/HPSPWC/servers/esecbmisrbo/tmp/_WL_user/acs-enrollment-ws/ogsp7w/war/WEB-INF/**lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar**
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:155)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)

Please note  that  the framework is  looking for my class in the wrong package :

**com/hps/common/crypto/api/**  but my package is  **com/hps/esecure/common/crypto/api/** .

in my spring configuration file  , i have the below :

**context:component-scan base-package="com.hps.esecure" **

the application is deployed correctly in Weblogic **12.2.1.1.0**  .